# Looking for a faster way to shift values in a pandas dataframe column based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to figure out a better/faster way to "march" values forward in one column when a certain threshold in another column is reached.
Sample dataframe, where 'Col1' and 'Col2' are inputs and 'Col4' is the desired output:

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.001 | 0.046667 | 13 | NaN |
| 1 | 0.002 | 0.051667 | 12 | NaN |
| 2 | 0.002 | 0.056667 | 11 | NaN |
| 3 | 0.003 | 0.061667 | 11 | NaN |
| 4 | 0.004 | 0.066667 | 10 | NaN |
| 5 | 0.005 | 0.073333 | 10 | NaN |
| 6 | 0.006 | 0.078333 | 10 | NaN |
| 7 | 0.007 | 0.083333 | 9 | NaN |
| 8 | 0.008 | 0.086667 | 9 | NaN |
| 9 | 0.009 | 0.091667 | 8 | NaN |
| 10 | 0.009 | 0.096667 | 8 | NaN |
| 11 | 0.009 | 0.100000 | 8 | NaN |
| 12 | 0.011 | 0.105000 | 7 | NaN |
| 13 | 0.012 | 0.110000 | 7 | 0.002 |
| 14 | 0.013 | 0.116667 | 6 | 0.004 |
| 15 | 0.012 | 0.121667 | 5 | 0.005 |
| 16 | 0.011 | 0.128333 | 4 | 0.007 |
| 17 | 0.010 | 0.136667 | 3 | 0.009 |
| 18 | 0.009 | 0.143333 | 2 | 0.009 |
| 19 | 0.008 | 0.150000 | 1 | 0.011 |

I would like to find each row where cumulative sum in 'Col2' starting with the current row reaches say 1 (will be a variable). Then I would like to shift or copy/paste values from 'Col1' to those rows in a new column - 'Col4'.

'Col3' is the desired number of rows to shift by for each row and is there to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.

The following for loop works, but is quite slow on large datasets, takes about 5 seconds to process 10,000 rows:

```
   for x in range(len(df)):
       ind = df.loc[x::, 'Col2'].cumsum().searchsorted(1)
       df.loc[x + ind, 'Col4'] = df.loc[x, 'Col1']
```

I would really appreciate any help in speeding this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to achieve considerable performance improvement by converting columns into np.arrays and getting rid of df.loc[].

my code now is:

```
col1 = df['Col1'].values
col2 = df['Col2'].values
df['Col4'] = pd.Series(data=([np.nan] * len(df)))
col4 = df['Col4'].values
k = len(df)
n = 1
for x in range(k):
    ind = col2[x::].cumsum().searchsorted(n)
    if x+ind >= k-1: break 
    col4[x+ind] = col1[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

- have looked at a number of approaches

  1. custom **cumsum()** that stops once limit has been reached
  2. improve 1 using `numba`
  3. a `numpy` solution that creates a new array
- the **shift** / **offset** is better expressed as the index so it can be used in `iloc`
- if you want value of **Col1** where `cumsum() > n` your sample looks wrong
- performance timings lower down...

```
from numba import jit

NaN = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.009, 0.009, 0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.012, 0.011, 0.01, 0.009, 0.008], 
 "Col2": [0.046667, 0.051667, 0.056667, 0.061667, 0.066667, 0.073333, 0.078333, 0.083333, 0.086667, 0.091667, 0.096667, 0.1, 0.105, 0.11, 0.116667, 0.121667, 0.128333, 0.136667, 0.143333, 0.15], 
 "Col3": [13, 12, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
 "Col4": [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.002, 0.004, 0.005, 0.007, 0.009, 0.009, 0.011]})

@jit(nopython=True)
def minidxjit(s, n=1):
    t=0
    i=0
    for v in s:
        t+=v
        if t>n: break
        i += 1
    return i if t>n else -1

def minidx(s, n=1):
    t=0
    for i,v in enumerate(s):
        t+=v
        if t>n: break
    return i if t>n else -1


def lkup(dfa, idx=False, n=1, jit=True):
    i = minidxjit(dfa.loc[:,"Col2"].values, n=n) if jit else minidx(dfa.loc[:,"Col2"].values, n=n)
    if idx: return i
    else: return np.nan if i==-1 else dfa.iloc[i,0]

n=1

df.assign(sh=pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda x: df.iloc[x:,1].cumsum().searchsorted(n)),
          sh2=pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda x: lkup(df.iloc[x:,], idx=True, n=n)),
          val=pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda x: lkup(df.iloc[x:,], n=n)),

         )

def faststuff(df, timeit=False):
    d = {"Col3f":[np.argmin(np.cumsum(df.Col2.values[s:])<n) for s in range(len(df))],
        "Col3fr":[np.argmin(np.cumsum(df.Col2.values[s:])<n)+s for s in range(len(df))],
        "Col4f":[df.iloc[np.argmin(np.cumsum(df.Col2.values[s:])<n)+s,0] for s in range(len(df))]}
    if timeit:
        d.pop("Col3f",None)
        d.pop("Col3fr",None)
    return df.assign(**d)

faststuff(df)
```

#### output on sample data

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col3f | Col3fr | Col4f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.001 | 0.046667 | 13 | nan | 13 | 13 | 0.012 |
| 1 | 0.002 | 0.051667 | 12 | nan | 12 | 13 | 0.012 |
| 2 | 0.002 | 0.056667 | 11 | nan | 11 | 13 | 0.012 |
| 3 | 0.003 | 0.061667 | 11 | nan | 11 | 14 | 0.013 |
| 4 | 0.004 | 0.066667 | 10 | nan | 10 | 14 | 0.013 |
| 5 | 0.005 | 0.073333 | 10 | nan | 10 | 15 | 0.012 |
| 6 | 0.006 | 0.078333 | 10 | nan | 10 | 16 | 0.011 |
| 7 | 0.007 | 0.083333 | 9 | nan | 9 | 16 | 0.011 |
| 8 | 0.008 | 0.086667 | 9 | nan | 9 | 17 | 0.01 |
| 9 | 0.009 | 0.091667 | 8 | nan | 8 | 17 | 0.01 |
| 10 | 0.009 | 0.096667 | 8 | nan | 8 | 18 | 0.009 |
| 11 | 0.009 | 0.1 | 8 | nan | 8 | 19 | 0.008 |
| 12 | 0.011 | 0.105 | 7 | nan | 7 | 19 | 0.008 |
| 13 | 0.012 | 0.11 | 7 | 0.002 | 0 | 13 | 0.012 |
| 14 | 0.013 | 0.116667 | 6 | 0.004 | 0 | 14 | 0.013 |
| 15 | 0.012 | 0.121667 | 5 | 0.005 | 0 | 15 | 0.012 |
| 16 | 0.011 | 0.128333 | 4 | 0.007 | 0 | 16 | 0.011 |
| 17 | 0.01 | 0.136667 | 3 | 0.009 | 0 | 17 | 0.01 |
| 18 | 0.009 | 0.143333 | 2 | 0.009 | 0 | 18 | 0.009 |
| 19 | 0.008 | 0.15 | 1 | 0.011 | 0 | 19 | 0.008 |

#### timing code

```
dfp=pd.concat([df for i in range(1000)]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(f"rows: {len(dfp)}")

%timeit pd.Series(dfp.index).apply(lambda x: lkup(df.iloc[x:,], n=n, jit=True))
%timeit pd.Series(dfp.index).apply(lambda x: lkup(df.iloc[x:,], n=n, jit=False))
%timeit faststuff(dfp,timeit=True)
```

#### timing results

```
rows: 20000
6.45 s ± 414 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
5.69 s ± 549 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
5.66 s ± 387 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time to look at this. When tested on a real dataset it takes about same 5 seconds to complete and shift values in the wrong direction? For each row in Col1 I need to find row index in Col2 where sum reaches 1 for example (can be any number) and then copy value from that row to that new (later) index in Col4. Col2 is the speed with which values in Col1 migrate forward in space. It can vary from 0 to 1.75, so many points will end up on the same new index and overwrite each other. The loop in my question does exactly what I need, I'm looking for performance improvement